# Get Content ID loaded in MasterPage ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: .net, asp.net

is there a way to get element ID of an Content element loaded in the master page PlaceHolder?

For EX:
My master page,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Below is Other Page using Master page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
I am the child page
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

how to get the Content ID ("Content2") in Master PageLoad.

Can Any one please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your real goal to get to the controls inside that content section (ie, the "lbl" label)?

Comment: I need to get Content Section ID(ie, "Content2")

Comment: @sandeep: have you tried code snippet I've provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible. The `asp:Content` controls are not actually part of the page's control hierarchy, as it says in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.content.aspx):

> A Content control is not added to the control hierarchy at runtime.
>   Instead, the contents within the Content control are directly merged
>   into the corresponding ContentPlaceHolder control.

That's why I asked about whether your ultimate goal was to access the controls in that section. If it is, you can get to them through the `ContentPlaceHolder` control, because at runtime all the controls that were in the Content section are inside of it. You can do this in your masterpage:

```
Label lbl = ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("lbl") As Label;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've overriden MasterPage then you can access a protected [ContentPlaceHolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.contentplaceholders.aspx) collection:

```
public class YourMasterPage : MasterPage
{
    // in Page_Load try out
    foreach(var placeHolder in this.ContentPlaceHolders)
    {
        var contentPlaceHolder = placeHolder as ContentPlaceHolder;
        if(contentPlaceHolder != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ID: " + contentPlaceHolder.ID);
            Debug.WriteLine("Client Id" + contentPlaceHolder.ClientID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried with this. But it il never enters into if Statement at all.

Comment: Please note that on .Net 4.0, MasterPage,ContentPlaceHolders in an IList of String objects (containing lowercase ContentPlaceHolder IDs), not ContentPlaceHolder objects. The documentation, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.contentplaceholders(v=vs.100).aspx, looks wrong in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can get like..

```
((ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1")).ClientID
```

Comment: I did minor change, please try now. There was bracket missing.

Comment: I used the above code in Master Template Page's PageLoad() Method in CodeBehind, even now i am getting error:System.NullReferenceException. Becoz Master itself is null

Comment: It's not working because this code is getting the placeholder id inside the master from the page code-behind, not what you wanted, which is getting the content section id inside the page from the master code-behind.